# how to echo a retrieved default value from a database column

Tags: php, mysqli, echo, mariadb, column-defaults

From a database I can retrieve a column's default value through the query below.
That is, I can from phpMyAdmin and dbForge Studio.  By means of mysqli one might, but I simply can't get the value (TINYINT) echoed.
Need it to fill (both correctable and hidden) form input boxes with a default value.
As a value, $btwl stays empty; the same code used on a single record in that column works.
So, I expect there is another type of fetching needed to echo that just one default cypher, but I can't find any documentation how to. Help is appreciated.

```
    require ("dbconn.inc.php");
    //this should be the desired output retrieved from information_schema
    $Qdefault = "SELECT column_default
          FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE table_name = 'keuken'
          AND column_name = 'BTW'
          LIMIT 1";
    $resultdefault = $mysqli->query($Qdefault);

      while ($row= $resultdefault->fetch_assoc()){
      $btwl= $row['BTW'];

      echo $row['BTW']. $row['Default']. $btwl . "%  at least 2x the value expected<br><br>";
        }
```

there is no value coming out of this. The default column value IS filled.
The query is double checked and gives the expected value 6 as a result in phpMyAdmin and dbForge Studio on both remote host and local.

```
SELECT CREATE TABLE KEUKEN
  CREATE TABLE `keuken` (    
  `ArtNr` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,  
  `reeks` varchar(16) NOT NULL COMMENT 'binnen                                                         
        reeks op hoofdingredient of gang',                                                       
  `groep` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `omschrijving` varchar(32) NOT NULL, 
  `Prijs_Incl` decimal(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,                                                    
  `Prijs_Excl` decimal(10,4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,              
  `variaties` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT       
              'sterretje in tabel',               
  `aantal` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,   
  `BTW` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '7',     
   PRIMARY KEY (`ArtNr`)    
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[SELECT column_default etc, format by Paul T. in dbForge client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbHze.png)

```
    $Q = "SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` where 
    table_name = 'keuken'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($Q);
    while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['column_default'];
```

and that worked, result as expected.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE ABLE keuken`

Comment: You are selecting a column named `column_default`, and nothing else. There is no `$row['BTW']` whatever that is.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, Havenard. But then, whatever BTW might mean (VAT in English, FYI), what IS IT and how can I fetch that default value. 'column_default' is what I understood not a column itself, but a value from the column as described in information_schema. See that CREATE TABLE as added.

Comment: can't add photo's yet, but the link to an image of my output is clickable, Paul T.

Comment: @DaviddeBeer: Yes, I saw that, and I noted the output in the bottom-left corner is `MediumText`, but I'm not sure what the 7 below that means for the tool that you use? That IS the column that you queried, so what exactly are you looking for if that is not desired result?  Check the same column in phpMyAdmin to see if it matches?

Comment: @PaulT. that 7 will soon be set back to 6. It is the value I need for calculations, Low tariff VAT percentage that should be the default value for form input. And changed from the owner's part of the website, whenever tariff changes (rumours, rumours...) within few months or maybe a lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the name of the column is actually `column_default`, and your SELECT query has the same column. So, `BTW` would not be part of the query results, and neither would `Default`.

Can you check that, and then you should only need:

```
echo $row['column_default'];
```

So for my test run:

```
SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` where table_name = 'tryMe' and column_name = 'date'
```

[image]

...and from the mysql client:
[image]

=====

UPDATE:

PHP output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["column_default"]=> string(17) "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" } }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  But that works for a filled record; it is just the DEFAULT value of the column that I can't fetch through PHP (while phpMyAdmin can). When the column's default is changed, the query above returns the new value. But in the admin tools only, not in my code.

Comment: Again paul, I can run the query in the clients, but in the PHP code the result is nada, nothing.. this seems not to be the solution

Comment: Again, yes I have a client example, but I do not see anywhere in the PHP where you have `$row['column_default']` from the query?   The `$row['BTW']` and `$row['Default']` do NOT exist in the query result to show any value.

Comment: Updated the answer to show example PHP output. Please see your query in the question above, there is only one column that you SELECT, which does **not** include the last two mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the databases values using Php , you will be using Mysqli

```
$query="SELECT email_id FROM students";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

the column values are stored as array in the `$result` variable

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

A Benefit of using mysqli_fetch_array() is that you can call the query value using both indexing as well as column name!